# ReactJS process.env.NODE_ENV is not set to production when using Dockerfile at Google Cloud Run

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-run

I have a ReactJS website that I am running in Google Cloud Run using Dockerfile.

The website in Google Cloud Run still shows the variable NODE_ENV to development, even after I have specified it to be production in my Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine 

# Set the working directory to /app inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy app files
COPY . .

# Install dependencies (npm ci makes sure the exact versions in the lockfile gets installed)
RUN npm ci 

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Set the env to "production"
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Expose the port on which the app will be running (3000 is the default that `serve` uses)
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Login() {
  // Backend URL
  let backendURL = ""
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"){
    backendURL = "https://localhost:5000"
  }
  else{
    backendURL = "https://my-website.a.run.app"
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <p>Please Log in {process.env.NODE_ENV}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**This gives**

> ```
> Please Log in development
> ```

I have also tried to assign the variable as Enviroment variable by clicking "Edit and deploy new Revision":

[image]

Comment: In your code, print the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to assist with debugging. My answer is correct, something else is wrong. As a test, deploy using the CLI command. Click the **SHOW COMMAND LINE** button. Paste the command and results in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud Run, environment variables are not set in the Dockerfile. They are set via the deployment command.

[gcloud run deploy --set-env-vars[...]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-env-vars)

Tip: The `EXPOSE` statement also does nothing in Google Cloud Run.

Comment: I use Cloud Build trigger. My application code is stored at Github. When a new push is done to main it will build on Google Cloud Run using Dockerfile.

Comment: @Europa only certain parts of a Dockerfile are used by Cloud Run when building the container. Docker statements that affect the environment have no effect because the build and deploy steps are separate.

Comment: Could this be done from the cloud shell located at https://console.cloud.google.com ? How does the command know what type of application that I would want to deploy? Is this correct: 
gcloud run deploy --set-env-vars=[NODE_ENV=production]

Comment: `gcloud run deploy --set-env-vars=NODE_ENV=production`. Sometimes you must use quotes and escaped quotes depending on the data.